# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I updated my code thanks to your help. 
When I launch the app with Expo, the opening works but I lost my scan icon which does not appear in my screen. 
This icon appeared previously.
The idea is to scan some barcodes in order to display relevant data stemming from products.

Here is my new code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  AsyncStorage,
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";

function ProductsScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");

      setData(data);
      setisLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <>
      {data ? (
        <FlatList
          data={dataArray}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <Text>{item.brand}</Text>

              <View style={styles.scan}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="barcode-scan"
                  size={40}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </>
          )}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
export default ProductsScreen;
```

I would appreciate your comments please.

Comment: Make sure `AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");` is returning something and also it looks like you might need `JSON.parse()`

Comment: What are you expecting the `userData` item to contain? Seems like it may be undefined and you're not accounting for that case.

Comment: There's no return in data.map, change the curly braces to parenthesis or add the return statement before <>

Comment: Your `key={index}` will be rendered as text since it is outside of a tag. Instead of just `<>` you need `<React.Fragment key={index}>`, or better, instead of index use a unique ID from your `data` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return from `data.map` function to render the array items

```js
return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
   <>
    {data?.map((data, index) => {
      return <View key ={index}>
        <Text> {data.products_name_fr} </Text>
        <Text> {data.brands} </Text>
        <Text> {data.image_url} </Text>
        <View style={styles.scan}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="barcode-scan"
            size={40}
            color="black"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>;
    })}
    </>
  );
```

Or short-hand of return

```js
return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
  <>
    data?.map((data, index) => (
      <View key ={index}>
        <Text> {data.products_name_fr} </Text>
        <Text> {data.brands} </Text>
        <Text> {data.image_url} </Text>
        <View style={styles.scan}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="barcode-scan"
            size={40}
            color="black"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>;
    ))
   </> 
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your message.

Comment: I tried but I have still the same error message (undefined is not a function (near '...data.map'

Comment: I have the same error displayed in my screen: TypeError: undefined is not a function('near ...data.map...'). Any idea to fix this issue please?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, try it and update your question with updated code if you still get the issue.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I just updated my code. thanks for your help. I used a FlatList method and it works but I lost a precious icon to scan my products

Comment: If a comment really helped you solve you problem, you should accept and create another question for another issue with more specific detail.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I just voted for the answer. Do you have an idea concerning the issue I posted concerning my icon?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ? (optional chaining) to confirm data doesnt yield to undefined before mapping.

```
data?.map((data, index) => {return <>....</>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this but I have the same error. Besides, the part of code which begins from: const styles=Stylesheet.create seems to be not active

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductsScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");

      setisLoading(false);
      setData(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <>
      {data?.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            key ={index}
            <Text> {data.products_name_fr} </Text>
            <Text> {data.brands} </Text>
            <Text> {data.image_url} </Text>
            <View style={styles.scan}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="barcode-scan"
                size={40}
                color="black"
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    products: {
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
    },

    scan: {
      marginLeft: 30,
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      right: 20,
      marginBottom: 60,
      marginRight: 30,
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      backgroundColor: "#ff9234",
    },
  });
}
export default ProductsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit my code and I got another type of error : Invariant violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component. I will really appreciate your comments and support to fix this

```
return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <>
      data?.map((data, index) => (
      <>
        <Text> {data.products_name_fr} </Text>
        <Text> {data.brands} </Text>
        <Text> {data.image_url} </Text>
        <View style={styles.scan}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="barcode-scan"
            size={40}
            color="black"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </>
      ))
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't make new comment, Just updated your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the useEffect, set the data as array. Example

```
const = [data, setData] = useState([]); // do this in your state

setData([data]); //do this in your useEffet hook
```